# What's the best way to make the edge of this coin look good?

Tags: modeling

[image: Here's the coin.]

I would like to make it smooth looking, but shade smooth looks a bit strange with it. I was thinking of subdividing it but only the long way, but then I don't know how to smoothen it.

Comment: shade smooth _and_ go to object properties, open the normals panel, and select autosmooth.

Comment: How good is good?

Comment: Subdivision Surface modifier?